# Kubernetes service discovery using DNS fails

Tags: kubernetes, dns, service-discovery, replicaset

I want to understand how the `/etc/resolve.conf` is configured for each pod of a replicaSet for DNS server info, because I upgraded the cluster from 1.13 to 1.14 and it somehow changed the IP of the kube DNS server , and the existing replicaSet is injecting the old IP/info into the `/etc/resolve.conf` of new pods of that replicaSet, breaking the service discovery for those particular pods.

Even if it is not a cluster upgrade and one just re-deploy kube-dns, and it changes its IP, then how existing replicaSet or statefulSets behave when they add/increase more pods. On my side, currently, it's injecting the old info.

New deployments work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The pods will always inherit the specification from the [owner object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents), in this case, from the `ReplicaSet`.

Each `ReplicaSet` has a **pod template** that contains the *resolv.conf* registered configuration and won't change unless a new `Deployment` is rolled out (since RSs are dependents of the `Deployment` object):

`kubectl get rs YOUR_REPLICASET -o yaml | grep pod-template-hash -m 1`

In this case you can either rollout a new `Deployment` version or redeploy the *kube-dns/coreDNS*' YAML definition, keeping the original `clusterIP`:

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.11.0.12 # Old service address
```